# Disable non admin users to logon

Tags: windows-server-2008, user-management

I have installed Windows Server 2008 @ my office, I have created 2 admin accounts and one user account(publicly shared to all team members for backup of their data on some shared folders).

They are working fine. But some time when I was out of office, non admin user able to logon and access this machine.

So I would like to disable non admin user, which can not login on this machine, just access shared folders.

What should I do?

Answer (score 5):

By default, normal users cannot log in interactively to a Windows Server, so one of (at least) 2 things must have happened

1) They know an admin password (and logged in with that, or someone made their accounts admins, etc).

2) Users have been granted the log on locally right (this might have happened if the remote desktop user role is installed on that box, or more likely, if someone was trying to make a server behave like a terminal server but without installing the role)

In order to stop non-admins logging in, you need to find out what changes have been made to the default windows server configuration to allow them to log in, and reverse those changes.